# Series sum of Fractional Fibonacci Series

Tags: open-problem

Please help me proving that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F(n)/(10^{-(n+1)}) = 0.011235955...$

Where F(n) are the Fibonacci Numbers

Comment: There is an explicit formula for the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Work out $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-n}F(n)$ and then divide by $10$.

Comment: Multiply the sum by 10, then add it to the sum.

Comment: I find an exactly same question on another site: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1783319p11761653 (searched from [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24F%5Cleft(n%5Cright)%5Ctimes10%5E%7B-%5Cleft(n%2B1%5Cright)%7D%24%2C%20Fibonacci&p=1)). Hope it helps you.

Comment: @WeiZhong: this is *not* the same question ! There is a very significant difference.

Comment: @YvesDaoust where is the difference?

Comment: @WeiZhong: see my answer. I claim that the OP didn't ask the right question.

Comment: Did you really mean to have that $/$? If so, the answer is $\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first terms of the summation are

$$0.01+0.001+0.0002+0.00003+0.000005+0.0000008+0.00000013+0.000000021+0.0000000034+0.00000000055+0.000000000089+0.0000000000144+0.00000000000233=\color{green}{0.011235955}05573.$$

Then it is no more possible to have a carry on the last digit $5$ and the nine first decimals are exact.

---

For rigor, we can check that $F_n<2^n$. Indeed by induction

$$F_{n+2}=F_{n+1}+F_n<2^n+2^{n+1}<2^{n+2}$$
and $F_0<2^0$.

So the error in the above evaluation is less than

$$\frac4{5^{13}}=6.6\cdot10^{-10}.$$